# Date Range in GoogleBigQuery

Tags: date, datetime, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I am pulling data from Google BigQuery to Tableau.

In Tableau, I want a date filter which ranges from (selected date - 15)days to (selected date). The date filter in Tableau will look like- `11/12/2019 12:00:00 AM to 11/26/2019 11:59:59 PM`.

In BigQuery table, the data type of date is TIMESTAMP.

I want to write a query that takes the selected date and computes date 15 days backward so that in tableau I can go 15 days behind by using the filter. How do I do that?

Right now what I have is-

`cast(datetime_trunc (datetime(run_time), hour) as string) date_time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT <column list>
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE DATE(run_time) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: you just changed `current date` to `selected date` in your question. In my mind this does not change my answer - can you clarify if you see it same way - or you have issue here that I can help you further with

Comment: so the current_date will take today's date in Tableau. What I want is whenever I select a date in Tableau it automatically goes 15 days back from there and selects that range. However, I think this is something I will need to fix in Tableau than Google BigQuery. You see a way of doing this in GBQ?

Comment: I answered following question - `I want to write a query that takes the selected date and computes date 15 days backward` the rest is still on you :o)

Comment: Yes. Your answer definitely helps! Thanks @Mikhail :)